# char* producing unexpected results from procedure in nested structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct, char

I am developing a few procedures that is retrieving certain values from an xml doc, and using nested struct pointers to help me manage the data.

I am experiencing unexpected behaviour from a string value within one of my structs:

This is the procedure:

```
void parseInlineElements(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML *xmlFile){

do {
    if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("AdSystem")) == 0){

        xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->AdSystem = (char *)node->children->content; // does not work - displays �9;
        xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->AdSystem = "Works"; // works
        printf ((char *)node->children->content); // works
    }
    else if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("Creatives")) == 0){
        parseCreatives (doc, node->children, xmlFile);
    }

    } while((node = node->next));

}
```

This is the line that I am having issues with:

```
xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->AdSystem = (char *)node->children->content;
```

When I test the result in my program, the value looks like it's not pointing to the right place in memory as it produces garbage, i.e. : "�9" where the expected value is "Ad System"

If I store a test value "Works" - no problems here

And if I even print the node value, this also works : "Ad System"

Thanks in advance

- HEADER FILE

```
/*
* daastXML.h
 *
 *  Created on: Nov 27, 2015
 *      Author: hearme
 */

#ifndef DAASTXML_H_
#define DAASTXML_H_

#define VECTOR_INITIAL_CAPACITY 100

// Define a vector type
typedef struct {
    int size;               // slots used so far
    int capacity;           // total available slots
    struct daastAd *data;     // array of ads we're storing

    char * testData;
} VectorAds;

typedef struct {
    int size;               // slots used so far
    int capacity;           // total available slots
    struct daastCreative *data;     // array of ads we're storing
} VectorCreatives;

typedef struct {
    int size;
    int capacity;
    struct daastMediaFile *data;
} VectorMediaFiles;


struct daastInline {

    // Required elements
    char *AdTitle;
    char *Impression;
    VectorCreatives *Creatives;
    char *Category;

    // Optional elements
    char *AdSystem;
    char *Description;
    char *Advertiser;
    char *Expires;

    // Multiple survey urls
    // Multiple error urls

    char *Pricing;

    // Extensions - for custom xml extensions

};

struct daastXML {
    char *version;
    VectorAds *Ads;
};

struct daastAd {
    char *id;
    char *sequence;
    struct daastInline *Inline;
};

struct daastMediaFile {
    char *id;
    char *delivery;
    char *type;
    char *url;
    char *bitRate;
};

struct daastLinear {
    char *duration;
    VectorMediaFiles MediaFiles;

};

struct daastCreative {
    struct daastLinear linear;
};



// Main handler
void processDaast (char * filePath, struct daastXML *xmlFile);



// Methods used to manage Ads collection
void vectorAds_init(VectorAds *vector);
void vectorAds_append(VectorAds *vector, struct daastAd value);
struct daastAd vectorAds_get(VectorAds *vector, int index);
void vectorAds_set(VectorAds *vector, int index, struct daastAd value);
void vectorAds_double_capacity_if_full(VectorAds *vector);
void vectorAds_free(VectorAds *vector);

// Methods used to manage Creatives collection
void vectorCreatives_init(VectorCreatives *vector);
void vectorCreatives_append(VectorCreatives *vector, struct daastCreative value);
struct daastCreative VectorCreatives_get(VectorCreatives *vector, int index);
void vectorCreatives_set(VectorCreatives *vector, int index, struct daastCreative value);
void vectorCreatives_double_capacity_if_full(VectorCreatives *vector);
void vectorCreatives_free(VectorCreatives *vector);

// Methods used to manage Creatives collection
void vectorMediaFiles_init(VectorMediaFiles *vector);
void vectorMediaFiles_append(VectorMediaFiles *vector, struct daastMediaFile value);
struct daastMediaFile vectorMediaFiles_get(VectorMediaFiles *vector, int index);
void vectorMediaFiles_set(VectorMediaFiles *vector, int index, struct daastMediaFile value);
void vectorMediaFiles_double_capacity_if_full(VectorMediaFiles *vector);
void vectorMediaFiles_free(VectorMediaFiles *vector);


#endif /* DAASTXML_H_ */
```

C File
    /*
     * daastXML.c
     *
     *  Created on: Nov 27, 2015
     *      Author: hearme
     */

```
#ifndef DAASTXML_C_
#define DAASTXML_C_

#define XMLSTR(str) ((xmlChar *)(str))

#include "daastXML.h"
#include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void parseAds(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML *xmlFile);
void parseInline(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML *xmlFile);
void parseInlineElements(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML *xmlFile);
void parseCreatives(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML *xmlFile);
void parseCreativesElements(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML *xmlFile);
void parseCreativeElements(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML *xmlFile);
void parseLinear (xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML *xmlFile);
void parseMediaFiles (xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML *xmlFile);


void processDaast (char * filePath, struct daastXML *xmlFile){

    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlNodePtr node;

    doc = xmlParseFile(filePath);
    node = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);


    if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("DAAST")) == 0){

        xmlFile->version = (char *)xmlGetProp(node, XMLSTR("version"));
        parseAds(doc, node->children, xmlFile);

    }

    xmlFreeDoc(doc);

}

void parseAds(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML *xmlFile){

    // Allocate new instance of the VectorAds and assign it to the xmlFile, set default data
    VectorAds *Ads;
    Ads = (VectorAds *) malloc (sizeof(VectorAds));

    Ads->testData = "testData";
    xmlFile->Ads = Ads;

    // Initialise the vector
    vectorAds_init(xmlFile->Ads);



    do {
        if (node == NULL) break;
        if (xmlIsBlankNode(node)) continue;

    if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("Ad")) == 0) {

        // Set up new advert
        struct daastAd *newAd;
        newAd = (struct daastAd *) malloc (sizeof(struct daastAd));

        // Set add properties
        newAd->id = (char *)xmlGetProp(node, XMLSTR("id"));
        newAd->sequence = (char *)xmlGetProp(node, XMLSTR("sequence"));

        vectorAds_append(xmlFile->Ads, *newAd);

        // At this point we need to get the inline (or wrapper) info *** WRAPPER NOT INTEGRATED ***
        parseInline (doc, node->children, xmlFile);

    }
} while ((node = node->next));


}

void parseInline (xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML *xmlFile){


// Set up Inline Property Here
struct daastInline *Inline;
Inline = (struct daastInline *) malloc (sizeof(struct daastInline));

// Assing Inline Property
xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline = Inline;

do {
    if (node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE){
        if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("InLine")) == 0){

            // Various parses at this level
            parseInlineElements(doc, node->children, xmlFile);
            //xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->AdSystem = "AdSystem";

            // Should this be here?
            //parseCreatives (doc, node->children, xmlFile);

            break;
        }
    }
} while((node = node->next));
}

void parseInlineElements(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML *xmlFile){

// loop through Inline child elements, and pick out the values
//*
do {
    if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("AdSystem")) == 0){
        char *nodeValue = (char *) node->children->content;
        xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->AdSystem = malloc (sizeof(char));
        strcpy (xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->AdSystem, nodeValue);
    }
    else if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("AdTitle")) == 0){
        char *nodeValue = (char *) node->children->content;
        xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->AdTitle = malloc (sizeof(char));
        strcpy (xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->AdTitle, nodeValue);
    }
    else if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("Category")) == 0){
        char *nodeValue = "";
        nodeValue = (char *) node->children->content;
        xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->Category = malloc (sizeof(char));
        strcpy (xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->Category, nodeValue);
    }
    else if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("Advertiser")) == 0){
        char *nodeValue = (char *) node->children->content;
        xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->Advertiser = malloc (sizeof(char));
        strcpy (xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->Advertiser, nodeValue);
    }
    else if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("Pricing")) == 0){
        char *nodeValue = (char *) node->children->content;
        xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->Pricing = malloc (sizeof(char));
        strcpy (xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->Pricing, nodeValue);
    }
    else if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("Expires")) == 0){
        char *nodeValue = (char *) node->children->content;
        xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->Expires = malloc (sizeof(char));
        strcpy (xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->Expires, nodeValue);
    }
//      else if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("Impression")) == 0){
//          char *nodeValue = (char *) node->children->next->content;
//          xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->Impression = malloc (sizeof(char));
//          strcpy (xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->Impression, nodeValue);
//
//      }
    else if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("Creatives")) == 0){
        parseCreatives (doc, node->children, xmlFile);
    }

} while((node = node->next));

}


void parseCreatives(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML *xmlFile){

// Need to set up a new Creatives and assign it to the nested struct pointer
VectorCreatives *Creatives;
Creatives = (VectorCreatives *) malloc (sizeof(VectorCreatives));

VectorAds *Ads;
Ads = (VectorAds *) malloc (sizeof(VectorAds));

xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->Creatives = Creatives;

vectorCreatives_init(xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->Creatives);

//*parseCreativesElements(doc, node->next, xmlFile);

}


void parseCreativesElements(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML *xmlFile){

do {

    // Loop through the creatives - find the individual Creatives
    if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("Creative")) == 0){

        // Various parses at this level
        parseCreativeElements(doc, node->children, xmlFile);
    }

} while ((node = node->next));
}

void parseCreativeElements(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML *xmlFile){

do {
    if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("Linear")) == 0){
        // Linear branch
        parseLinear(doc, node->children, xmlFile);

    } else if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("CompanionAds")) == 0){
        // Companion Ad branch

    }
} while ((node = node->next));

}

void parseLinear(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML *xmlFile){

do {

    if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("Duration")) == 0){

        struct daastCreative newCreative;

        //*newCreative.linear.duration = node->children->content;

        //*vectorCreatives_append(&xmlFile->Ads.data->Inline.Creatives, newCreative);

    } else if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("MediaFiles")) == 0){
        //parseMediaFiles(doc,node->children,xmlFile);
    }
} while ((node = node->next));

}


void parseMediaFiles(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node, struct daastXML *xmlFile){

//* vectorMediaFiles_init(&xmlFile->Ads.data->Inline.Creatives.data->linear.MediaFiles);

do {

    // Store all occurrences of Media Files
    if (xmlStrcmp (node->name, XMLSTR("MediaFile")) == 0){

        // Create a new Media File, and append
        struct daastMediaFile newMediaFile;

        newMediaFile.url = (char *) node->children->next->content;

        newMediaFile.id = (char *)xmlGetProp(node, XMLSTR("id"));
        newMediaFile.type = (char *)xmlGetProp(node, XMLSTR("type"));
        newMediaFile.bitRate = (char *)xmlGetProp(node, XMLSTR("bitrate"));
        newMediaFile.delivery = (char *)xmlGetProp(node, XMLSTR("delivery"));

        //*vectorMediaFiles_append(&xmlFile->Ads.data->Inline.Creatives.data->linear.MediaFiles, newMediaFile);

    }
} while ((node = node->next));

}


// ***************************************************************
// ***************************************************************
// ***************************************************************
// ***************************************************************


// Methods to manage collection (Ads)

void vectorAds_init(VectorAds *vector) {
  // initialize size and capacity
  vector->size = 0;
  vector->capacity = VECTOR_INITIAL_CAPACITY;

  // allocate memory for vector->data
  vector->data = malloc(sizeof(struct daastAd) * vector->capacity);
}

void vectorAds_append(VectorAds *vector, struct daastAd value) {
  // make sure there's room to expand into
  vectorAds_double_capacity_if_full(vector);

  // append the value and increment vector->size
  vector->data[vector->size++] = value;
}

struct daastAd vectorAds_get(VectorAds *vector, int index) {
  if (index >= vector->size || index < 0) {
    printf("Index %d out of bounds for vector of size %d\n", index, vector->size);
    exit(1);
  }
  return vector->data[index];
}

void vectorAds_set(VectorAds *vector, int index, struct daastAd value) {
  // zero fill the vector up to the desired index
  struct daastAd zero;
  while (index >= vector->size) {
    vectorAds_append(vector, zero);
  }

  // set the value at the desired index
  vector->data[index] = value;
}

void vectorAds_double_capacity_if_full(VectorAds *vector) {
  if (vector->size >= vector->capacity) {
    // double vector->capacity and resize the allocated memory accordingly
    vector->capacity *= 2;
    vector->data = realloc(vector->data, sizeof(struct daastAd) * vector->capacity);
  }
}

void vectorAds_free(VectorAds *vector) {
  free(vector->data);
}


// Methods to manage Creatives Vector

void vectorCreatives_init(VectorCreatives *vector) {
  // initialize size and capacity
  vector->size = 0;
  vector->capacity = VECTOR_INITIAL_CAPACITY;

  // allocate memory for vector->data
  vector->data = malloc(sizeof(struct daastCreative) * vector->capacity);
}

void vectorCreatives_append(VectorCreatives *vector, struct daastCreative value) {
  // make sure there's room to expand into
  vectorCreatives_double_capacity_if_full(vector);

  // append the value and increment vector->size
  vector->data[vector->size++] = value;
}

struct daastCreative vectorCreatives_get(VectorCreatives *vector, int index) {
  if (index >= vector->size || index < 0) {
    printf("Index %d out of bounds for vector of size %d\n", index, vector->size);
    exit(1);
  }
  return vector->data[index];
}

void vectorCreatives_set(VectorCreatives *vector, int index, struct daastCreative value) {
  // zero fill the vector up to the desired index
  struct daastCreative zero;
  while (index >= vector->size) {
    vectorCreatives_append(vector, zero);
  }

  // set the value at the desired index
  vector->data[index] = value;
}

void vectorCreatives_double_capacity_if_full(VectorCreatives *vector) {
  if (vector->size >= vector->capacity) {
    // double vector->capacity and resize the allocated memory accordingly
    vector->capacity *= 2;
    vector->data = realloc(vector->data, sizeof(struct daastCreative) * vector->capacity);
  }
}

void vectorCreatives_free(VectorCreatives *vector) {
  free(vector->data);
}


// Methods used to manage MediaFiles Vector

void vectorMediaFiles_init(VectorMediaFiles *vector) {
  // initialize size and capacity
  vector->size = 0;
  vector->capacity = VECTOR_INITIAL_CAPACITY;

  // allocate memory for vector->data
  vector->data = malloc(sizeof(struct daastMediaFile) * vector->capacity);
}

void vectorMediaFiles_append(VectorMediaFiles *vector, struct daastMediaFile value) {
  // make sure there's room to expand into
  vectorMediaFiles_double_capacity_if_full(vector);

  // append the value and increment vector->size
  vector->data[vector->size++] = value;
}

struct daastMediaFile vectorMediaFiles_get(VectorMediaFiles *vector, int index) {
  if (index >= vector->size || index < 0) {
    printf("Index %d out of bounds for vector of size %d\n", index, vector->size);
    exit(1);
  }
  return vector->data[index];
}

void vectorMediaFiles_set(VectorMediaFiles *vector, int index, struct daastMediaFile value) {
  // zero fill the vector up to the desired index
  struct daastMediaFile zero;
  while (index >= vector->size) {
    vectorMediaFiles_append(vector, zero);
  }

  // set the value at the desired index
  vector->data[index] = value;
}

void vectorMediaFiles_double_capacity_if_full(VectorMediaFiles *vector) {
  if (vector->size >= vector->capacity) {
    // double vector->capacity and resize the allocated memory accordingly
    vector->capacity *= 2;
    vector->data = realloc(vector->data, sizeof(struct daastMediaFile) * vector->capacity);
  }
}

void vectorMediaFiles_free(VectorMediaFiles *vector) {
  free(vector->data);
}

#endif /* DAASTXML_C_ */
```

Link to XML : http://hearme.fm/ars.xml

Comment: And the memory pointed to by `node->children->content` will stay valid the entire time you need it? You don't `free` it anywhere before you use `xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->AdSystem`? How do you check the contents of the memory? Where do you check it? `node->children->content` *have* ben initialized to point to valid allocated memory? Why do you cast the pointer? Can you show us the structure definitions, or at least the relevant parts? If you remove the cast, do you get any compiler warnings or errors? What if you enable more warnings (add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` if using GCC or Clang)?

Comment: You should not `printf` a string directly, it could cause a problem if there are formatting characters in the string.

Comment: I'm fairly new to C, but I suspect what you are saying is that because ->AdSystem is effectively pointing to a value created by node, when the node is free'd up, so is the value? Is that correct?

I am checking the value in my main procedure, I first parse the xml doc, free the doc, then return the xmlFile.

In this case, what is the best way to assign this value? I suspect creating a direct copy is the correct method?

Comment: No warnings if I remove the cast

Comment: Code:

`struct daastInline {

 char *AdTitle;
 char *Impression;
 VectorCreatives Creatives;
 char *Category;

 // Optional elements
 char *AdSystem;
 char *Description;
 char *Advertiser;
 char *Expires;
 char *Pricing;
};`

Comment: Are you checking `xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->AdSystem` before or *after* the assignment? Oh, and please don't add code in comments, please edit your question to include that instead.

Comment: I'm checking it after the assignment

Comment: OK - If I don't free up my xmlDocPtr, the value is correctly displayed. So I guess I just need to directly copy the string value in the node to the struct property. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Why do you think you have to cast the value in the assignment? Generally casts are not a good idea, since they may just hide problems, instead of solving them.

Comment: @JensGustedt, I have to make the cast otherwise I receive a warning : pointer targets in assignment differ in signedness. But, I don't think this is causing my errors

Comment: @GlennCooper, at least it shows that you have a conceptual problem somewhere. `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are all different types and for good reasons.

Comment: For a simple problem, this seems overly complicated? All I want to do is assign a value from the node to my struct property

Comment: The `node->children->content` is of type xmlChar, that's why the cast is required. http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlstring.html#xmlChar

Comment: See above edit for header and source

Answer (score 1):

OK,

I've fixed the error, but it doesn't look the cleanest of code, maybe someone can advise if this is fine?

```
char *nodeValue = (char*) node->children->content;
xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->AdSystem = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char));
strcpy (xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->AdSystem, nodeValue);
```

Comment: No, it is not. 1) you cast the result of `malloc()`, don't do that. 2) you allocate one byte of memory, which is already used by the `nul` in the end of the string. So you must only empty strings for this to *not* go over the memory allocated. You must allocate the proper amount of memory.

Comment: You need to allocate enough memory. Should be `malloc(strlen(nodeValue)+1);`. That being said, you need to study the basics of strings before doing things like this.

Comment: Back to the original problem, does anyone have a simple and effective manner to assign a value from the node value? This seems to be more complicated than it should be

Comment: @GlennCooper, for us it is complicated because you are not showing us everything. Produce a minimal complete example such that we see all your types and that we even might compile it ourselves. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->AdSystem is simply nested structs. The node->children->content is of type xmlChar (http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlstring.html#xmlChar). All I need to do is assign a string value from the node to my struct

Comment: @JensGustedt - see above for header and source

Answer (score 0):

> I've fixed the error, but it doesn't look the cleanest of code, maybe
>   someone can advise if this is fine?
>
> ```
> char *nodeValue = (char*) node->children->content;
> xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->AdSystem = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char));
> strcpy (xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->AdSystem, nodeValue);
> ```

Sami Kuhmonen and Lundin already noted that the allocated size isn't.

> Back to the original problem, does anyone have a simple and effective
>   manner to assign a value from the node value? This seems to be more
>   complicated than it should be

You're right; if you have a POSIX system, the above can be simplified by use of [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html):

```
xmlFile->Ads->data->Inline->AdSystem = strdup((char *)node->children->content);
```